# C# Google Geocoding: Constantly Getting Permission Denied Even When following the Steps Required

Tags: c#, api, google-maps, geocoding

I am creating an app in which it is needed to convert a street number to latitude and longitude so it can be shown on a map. I decided I would use Google's Geocoding  API.

For starters - I created a basic application in a console which would convert a given street number to a latitude and longitude value.

I also created an API key in the Google API Console.

```
Geocoding.IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() { ApiKey = "my api key" };
            IEnumerable<Address> addresses =  await geocoder.GeocodeAsync("1600 pennsylvania ave washington dc");
            Console.WriteLine("Formatted: " + addresses.First().FormattedAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Coordinates: " + addresses.First().Coordinates.Latitude + ", " + addresses.First().Coordinates.Longitude);

            Console.ReadKey();
```

When running the app - I get the following exception:

```
Geocoding.Google.GoogleGeocodingException: 'There was an error processing the geocoding request. See Status or InnerException for more information.'
```

There was no information in the InnerException - so I checked the status and it said this:

[image]

RequestDenied - thankfully this was a common problem - so I went to the following page to find a solution:

[image]

So first of all I made sure that the Places API was enabled/activated in the Google Cloud Console - it was activated.

[image]

I checked whether there were any issues with my key parameter - but I couldn't find any issues - it seemed to be fine. I generated a new api key just in case and it still did not work.

I also checked whether the API key had been correctly setup - I created a new API key that **was unrestricted and I was *still* getting the same problem.**

[image]

I've followed every step here and once again I am still getting the same problem: Request Denied.

I don't know if I am missing a really important step, but for now I have no idea what to do. I have tried for **hours** upon hours to fix this but to no avail.

**I don't know what the root of the problem is - I am offering 100 reputation to whoever can help me.**

Thanks,

tommy99

Comment: what happen when you visit this URL with your API key filled in? : "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY"  Get that working first....

Comment: Have a look at following article this may resolve your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998566/14882929

Comment: First check your api kye using this link
If you are able to get results then there might be some issues with your code. 

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 1):

How many requests do you send in a second?
I found this usage limit in the [usage limit documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits)

> While you are no longer limited to a maximum number of requests per day (QPD), the following usage limits still apply when using the Places API:

> Rate limit is 100 requests per second (QPS). It is calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side requests for all applications using the credentials of the same project.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @emert117 you might have reached usage limit. Moreover, Google has limited services in certain countries and for certain IP addresses. You might need to make sure requests don't go through a VPN or Proxy with a restricted IP address or don't originate from restricted countries.

These thread might have more helpful comments though:

1. [Google Geocoding API - REQUEST_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212550/google-geocoding-api-request-denied)
2. [Does Geocoder gem work with google API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750370/does-geocoder-gem-work-with-google-api-key)